# Google Maps change marker icon on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I change a marker icon when a marker is clicked (on a click event) and return it back to a normal icon when another marker is clicked?

How can I load the maps with a marker already clicked?

Also if it's possible to add some animations like transitions when click on icon.

```
function initialize() {
    /* Lat. and Lon. of the center of the map */
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42.8012564, 10.75113);

    // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
    // to the map type control.
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,               //zoom level
        center: myCenter,       //center position
        scrollwheel: false,     //zoom when scroll disable
        zoomControl: true,      //show control zoom
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'],
        }
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

    var image1 = 'http://puntaala.noonicbeta.com/wp-content/themes/Wordpress/img/marker-grey.svg';



                  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.80207599824027, 10.756003014830668),
                      map: map,
                      icon: image1,
                      title: 'Hotel',
                      description: 'Magna exercitation id culpa eiusmod velit veniam. Cillum eiusmod irure dolore officia proident eiusmod Lorem dolore. Enim cupidatat esse laborum minim sint laborum ad duis ea est adipisicing incididunt ut veniam. Aliqua exercitation aute nostrud labore cupidatat velit commodo tempor minim voluptate non quis voluptate. Cupidatat aute velit est reprehenderit eu fugiat aliquip est do [&hellip;]',
                      luogo: 'LA MAREMMA',
                      indirizzo: 'Costigliole della Pescaia',
                  });

                  function showClick (marker) {
                  var title = document.getElementById('title');
                  var description = document.getElementById('description');
                  var luogo = document.getElementById('luogo');
                  var indirizzo = document.getElementById('indirizzo');
                  title.innerHTML=marker.title;
                  description.innerHTML=marker.description;
                  indirizzo.innerHTML=marker.indirizzo;
                  luogo.innerHTML=marker.luogo;
                  marker.setIcon("http://puntaala.noonicbeta.com/wp-content/themes/Wordpress/img/marker.svg");
                  }

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
                  showClick(marker2);
                  });


                  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.8012564, 10.75113),
                      map: map,
                      icon: image1,
                      title: 'Roccaforte',
                      description: 'ex ex reprehenderit aute exercitation cupidatat deserunt irure cillum sit ad culpa aliqua aliqua cupidatat anim exercitation commodo incididunt proident adipisicing fugiat excepteur elit voluptate incididunt minim esse ea incididunt voluptate amet ipsum quis sunt ullamco non consequat non eiusmod dolore nulla occaecat mollit pariatur cupidatat aliquip adipisicing voluptate nulla esse labore ad ipsum quis [&hellip;]',
                      luogo: 'La Maremma',
                      indirizzo: 'Costigliole della Pescaia',
                  });

                  function showClick (marker) {
                  var title = document.getElementById('title');
                  var description = document.getElementById('description');
                  var luogo = document.getElementById('luogo');
                  var indirizzo = document.getElementById('indirizzo');
                  title.innerHTML=marker.title;
                  description.innerHTML=marker.description;
                  indirizzo.innerHTML=marker.indirizzo;
                  luogo.innerHTML=marker.luogo;
                  marker.setIcon("http://puntaala.noonicbeta.com/wp-content/themes/Wordpress/img/marker.svg");
                  }

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
                  showClick(marker1);
                  });

          }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change a marker icon when a marker is clicked (on a click event) and return it back to a normal icon when another marker is clicked?

You could use the google maps api to use the "Info Window" Function of the markers. The handling of only having one active window is done already. You can check out [the Info Window Documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) for that.
If you want to do it yourself however you can save all markers in an array globally and have a function to "deselect" all others but the one you just now selected. Just like your "showClick(marker)" function, just the other way round.

> How can i load the maps with a marker already clicked?

For this you could call your showClick(marker1) function at the end of the initialize function, or when you are using the "Info Windows" from the google maps api you can call infowindow.open(map, marker) respectively at the end if your initialize function.

> Also if it's possibile to add some animations like transitions when click on icon.

The google maps api also supports this. You can check out [the Marker Animation Documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations) to check out how it's possible